# Make React useEffect only run at initial render and when property changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a useEffect that I want only to be run on the **initial** render and when a variable changes. That means that I don't want it to be run every time the component rerenders. This is where I'm stuck, this is my current code simplified:

```
useEffect(() => {
       // Some logic only to be performed when variable changes OR at initial render
    }, [variable]);
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: your code should already work as described ^; could you create a working example where it isn't so that we have help debug

Comment: It is working, but not as I want.. The problem with that code is that it rerenders every time the component mounts, where I only want it to be run on the initial load.

Comment: could you add a complete example? if the component is unmounting & remounting - for eg, say you are doing - `{ isVisible && <YourComponent /> }`... & isVisible is changing, i dont think you can prevent this at a hooks level, unless you do some sort of global memoization outside the component

Answer (score 2):

You need to conditionally run it on every render, so get rid of the dependency array and add conditions inside your useEffect.
Otherwise, you can make 2 useEffects, one with an empty dependency array, and the other with the state variable.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want your useEffect to run on initial render then do it like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
// do whatever you want to do here
},[]);
```

and in case you want it to run on some variable change then:

````
useEffect(() => {
       // Some logic only to be performed when variable changes OR at initial render
    }, [variable]);
    ```
````

Comment: The problem is that my component rerenders a lot due to changes in state and use of useMemo etc, so these useEffects will be run on every rerender in my component, where I only want it to run on the initial load/refresh of page (or when variable changes) ...